# Splitting sentences into strings across multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex, string, char

I'm trying to read and work with the text inside of a file. The problem is I need to split it into sentences and can't think of a way to do it...

Here's an example of the text file:

```
I went to a shop. I bought a pack of sausages 

and some milk. Sadly I forgot about the potatoes. I'm on my way 

to the store

to buy potatoes.
```

As you can see sentences can go across multiple lines before ending. I know I should use Regex but can't think of a way to do it...

Comment: Its really hard to determine what you are asking but I think what you are looking for is: remove all new line characters from the string, and then split that string by all the punctuation you need (`.` , `?` , `!` , etc)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here that you define sentence as any non-empty section of input separated by a period.

Maybe something along the lines of this:

```
(?<=^|\.)(.+?)(\.|$)
```

The key is probably that you should use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option so `.` would match any character (instead of any character except \n).

Explanation of the above pattern in more detail:

1. `(?<=^|\.)` is a [Zero-Width Positive Lookbehind Assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion) which requires your to-be-matches to be at the start of your input OR preceded by period. The matched period itself will not be part of match.
2. `(.+?)` is your sentence content. the `+?` operator is called lazy as it will try to match as short section of input as possible. This is needed to ensure that it would not grab the period nor next sentences from next pattern part
3. `(\.|$)` would match the sentence terminator oR the end of input.

Full working example:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=^|\.)(.+?)(\.|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
String input = @"I went to a shop. I bought a pack of sausages
and some milk. Sadly I forgot about the potatoes. I'm on my way
to the store
to buy potatoes.";
foreach (var match in r.Matches(input))
{
    string sentence = match.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding up the separate lines into one solid string and then splitting it into a couple of sentences.

**This is the method i tried to use:**

```
static void Sakiniai (string fv, string skyrikliai)
    {
        char[] skyrikliaiSak = { '.', '!', '?' };

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        string naujas = "";

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            naujas += line;
            naujas += " ";
        }

        string[] sakiniai = naujas.Split(skyrikliaiSak);
        for(int i = 0; i < sakiniai.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sakiniai[i]);
        }

    }
```

Tell me is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Firstly, `string naujas = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)).Join(" ");` Also, what would you consider better?

Answer (score 0):

As @maccettura commented you can try something similiar to this.

```
string text = "...";
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ").Replace("  ", " ");
        var sentences = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '!', '?' });
        foreach(string s in sentences)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long your text can be, so just in case I would do it sentence by sentence.

Something like this:

```
        char[] periods = {'.', '!', '?'}; // or any other separator you may like

        string      line       = "";
        string      sentence   = "";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ("filename.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.IndexOfAny(periods)<0)
                {
                    sentence += " " + line.Trim(); // increment sentence if there are no periods

                    // do whatever you want with the sentence
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (sentence))
                        process(sentence);

                    continue;
                }

                // I'm using StringSplitOptions.None here so we handle lines ending with a period right
                string[] sentences = line.Split(periods, StringSplitOptions.None);

                for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
                {
                    sentence += " " + line.Trim(); // increment sentence if there are no periods

                    // do whatever you want with the sentence
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
                        process(sentence);

                    // we don't want to clean on the last piece of sentence as it will continue on the next line
                    if (i < sentences.Length - 1)
                    {
                        sentence = ""; // clean for next sentence
                    }
                }

            }

            // this step is only required if you might have the last line sentence ending without a period
            // do whatever you want with the sentence
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
                process(sentence);
```

(Please note that if you know that you are only handling small files you don't need all of this and you would be fine with the previous suggestions)